# Unable to start Apache Tomcat server while start up

Tags: tomcat7

When I try to start Apache tomcat 7.0.26 server is not starting. This is first time.

console message as follows :

> Mar 7, 2012 12:06:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 470 ms

Comment: That message is saying that Tomcat has started. Can you access it via http://localhost:8080?

Answer (score 0):

It has been started and the starting process took `470 ms`.
That's what the message says.

I have the *suspicion* that you didn't even bother to check the url of web management to see if Tomcat is up or not.